# iOS - Edit CoreData SQLite DB with Java

Tags: java, iphone, ios, sqlite, core-data

Is it possible to edit a CoreData SQLite database created by CoreData itself with Java? The problem I see is the relationships between tables... is there a library?

Thanks

Comment: A word of caution: Core Data is not SQL. Entities are not tables. Objects are not rows. Attributes are not columns. Relationships are not joins. Core Data is an object graph management system that may or may not persist the object graph and may or may not use SQL far behind the scenes to do so. Trying to think of Core Data in SQL terms will cause you to completely misunderstand Core Data and result in much grief and wasted time.

Comment: Further: Core Data isn't just a lightweight wrapper around SQL. You can't plan to use it like you would any SQL file or API. I have seen only a handful of successful direct accesses/modifications of the sqlite store file under Core Data and those took way, way longer than anticipated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, it's a SQLite database and can be opened and edited by any tool that understands SQLite 3. The problem is that the table schema is undocumented and rather opaque, especially as you guessed when it comes to relationships. Editing the tables is generally not advisable, though occasionally it can be useful to inspect them. There are Mac OS X apps that will open a Core Data store if you provide a managed object model (e.g. http://christian-kienle.de/CoreDataEditor/) but that relies on the Mac's built-in Core Data library.

What are you actually trying to accomplish here?

Comment: I would like to populate the db via java for an iPhone app... but if the db is ORM it would be better! So I was wondering if I could use CoreData but if there is an alternative, it would be good too.

Comment: If you plan to use the data in Core Data then the only really reliable way to pre-populate the data store is to use Core Data on a Mac. If you wanted to use SQLite directly in the iPhone app you could pre-populate it using any tool that understands SQLite, but you could not then use this database with Core Data.